Password protected Excel file on usb drive file behaving strangely when clicked
Nothing unusual at first glance - a password-protected Excel file on a usb stick.  Previously, put the stick in the usb port, double-click the file and enter the password to work on the file.
Now though, when I put the stick in the usb port, the file opens (a copy) on just a single-click and the explorer window shuts down when the password is entered, meaning that I can't access the file contents.
Very odd behaviour - tried a variety of usb sticks in various usb ports (same machine, same file).
I checked, and File Explorer options are not set to open on single-click.  Copying the file to the desktop allows it to open and behave normally.  Tried said file on a micro sd card, same problem as with the usb sticks, so it's one particular file on any removable media that seems to be the source of the problem.
Any ideas as to a likely cause?

To see if it's something Windows remembers, e.g., open on single-click, make a copy of that file, and change the filename, then put it on USB. If that file behaves normally, blame Windows 11.

Good idea.  I'll give that a go and report back...

Tried what you suggested, but problem persisted, so created a clean file on a different machine and copied the worksheet contents from the corrupted file.  That seems to have fixed the problem.

Make sure your USB stick wasn't affected by malware first! Some USB malware can try to hide the files in your USB stick and replace them with executables with the same name. And you would risk running the virus when you double-click them.
